# Fill in a cell with text if a range of cells has any text

Tags: excel, if-statement, indexing, match, auto-populate

Does anyone know of a function or command in excel that will fill in a cell if there is any text in a range of cells?

I am building a database but am having trouble filling in the study type when there is multiple study types. I have been able to fill in a single cell from another sheet with an "IF" command with "INDEX" and "MATCH", however I'm trying to fill in a single cell from multiple sheets that have different text. Below is an example of the database I'm working with and an example of my "IF" function that works for one "Study Type".

[image]

=IF('Photo Point Study'!$A2="",0,(INDEX('Photo Point Study'!$D$2:$D$4720,MATCH('Photo Point Study'!$A2,'MLSNF Veg Studies'!$A$2:$A$4720,0))))

Any ideas on how to fill in the "Study Type" from the cells on the right (E:J)?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(E2&F2&G2&H2&I2&J2,0,"")
```

in Row2 and copied down to suit.